# setOnClickListener on a View larger than Parent's height

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a view overlapping its parent's height, however, when I set setOnClickListener, it doesn't detect clicking outside the parent's boundaries.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#D9D9D9"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/snapshotLine"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>       
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried, doing, cardview.bringToFront(), but still doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Why not make the parent the same size?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this post](https://suragch.medium.com/how-touch-events-are-delivered-in-android-eee3b607b038) on *Medium*.

When you touch the child view (*CardView*), it is the parent that receives the initial touch and propagates it to the *CardView*. When you touch the *CardView* outside of its parent, the parent doesn't see the touch event at all, so can't propagate it to its children. It is the view that in under the *CardView* where you touch it that receives the touch event. Since the *CardView* is not its child, the touch event doesn't register.

<s>Look into placing the *CardView* into another *ViewGroup* that wraps the *CardView's* content. That *ViewGroup* should receive all touches on the *CardView* and be able to propagate them to the *CardView*.</s> (Try this if you want, but I'm fairly sure that this won't work. I don't think that there is an easy solution, although you could capture the clicks on the underlying *ViewGroup* and forward them to the *CardView*.)

Comment: Thank you @Cheticamp, I will give it a try.